# Why does MSSQL procedure act differently called from Management Studio and from PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, moodle

I have a main procedure, which calls sub-procedures. The main procedure has no param, it's only calls the sub-procedures. (the sub-procedures are the same with different params)
The sub-procedures makes inserts and updates from a view. If I run from Management Studio everything seems ok, after a 3 minutes I have about 1000 message says '(1 row(s) affected)'.
But when I call it from PHP, then it runs for about 1 seconds with no error, and only the first sub-procedure has an effect. If I remove the first procedure, then only second procedure has an effect.
The PHP use the same user as Management Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I run from Management Studio everything seems ok, after a 3 minutes I have about 1000 message says '(1 row(s) affected)'. But when I call it from PHP, then it runs for about 1 seconds with no error, and only the first sub-procedure has an effect.

The '(1 row(s) affected)' message you see in SSMS is in response to a [message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/43e891c5-f7a1-432f-8f9f-233c4cd96afb) sent to the client.  If the client isn't consuming these messages, it can block the server-side execution.

To try to add [set nocount on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) at the beginning of your main procedure, and verify in SSMS that the row count messages have disappeared:

> SET NOCOUNT ON prevents the sending of DONE_IN_PROC messages to the
>   client for each statement in a stored procedure. For stored procedures
>   that contain several statements that do not return much actual data,
>   or for procedures that contain Transact-SQL loops, setting SET NOCOUNT
>   to ON can provide a significant performance boost, because network
>   traffic is greatly reduced.